# Executing php file from another php file

Tags: javascript, php

Can I trigger the execution of a php file from another php file when performing an action? More specific, I have an anchor generated with echo, that has href to a pdf file. In addition of downloading the pdf I want to insert some information into a table. Here's my code, that doesn't work:

```
require('./database_connection.php');
    $query = "select author,title,link,book_id from book where category='".$_REQUEST['categorie']."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $result2 = mysql_query("select user_id from user where username='".$_REQUEST["username"]."'");
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_row($result2);
    while($row= mysql_fetch_row($result))
   {
       echo '<h4>'.$row[0].' - '.$row[1].'</h4>';
       if(isset($_SESSION["username"]) && !empty($_SESSION["username"]))
       {
           echo '<input type="hidden" name="id_carte" value="'.$row[3].'">';
           echo '<input type="hidden" name="id_user" value="'.$row2[0].'">';
           echo '  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                   <script language="javascript">
                   function insert_download() {
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "insert_download.php" ,
                    success : function() { 
                    location.reload();
                    }
                    });
                    }
                  </script>
                  <a onclick="insert_download()" href="'.$row[2].'" download> download </a>';
                   }
```

And here's the insert_download.php:

```
    <?php
require('./database_connection.php');
$query = "insert into download(user_id,book_id,date)values(".
          $_REQUEST["id_carte"].",".
          $_REQUEST["id_user"].",".
          date("Y-m-d h:i:s").")";
mysql_query($query,$con); 
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: I don't get an error, it's just not working to execute insert_download.php. I've used alert to verify if the function is executed and it's ok, so I guess the problem is with the ajax part.

Comment: check with the console that it call your file not..just echo your query in file and checked with the console output.

Comment: i rewrote by response, maybe it can make more sense now.

Comment: Warning: your code is [vulnerable to SQL-injections](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Comment: I don't quite mean what you exactly want. You want to show a link on a certain page and then if a user clicks the link, **1.** some code is executed and **2.** a download dialog appears, allowing the user to download the PDF file. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand correctly, you want to display a link, and when the user clicks that link,

- some data is inserted into a database or something;
- the user sees a download dialog, allowing him to download a file?

If this is correct, you can use this code:

On your webpage:

```
<a href="result.php?file=dummy.pdf">download</a>
```

**result.php**:

```
<?php

$file = isset($_GET['file']) ? $_GET['file'] : "";

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Downloading...</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function redirect(url) {
            //window.location.replace(url);
            window.location.href = url;
        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Download is starting...
        <script type="text/javascript">

        redirect("http://example.com/download.php?file=dummy.pdf");

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**download.php**:

```
<?php

$file = isset($_GET['file']) ? $_GET['file'] : "nullfile";
$file_url = "download_dir_or_something/".$file;

// Put some line in a log file...
file_put_contents("logfile.txt", "successful on ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."\n", FILE_APPEND);
// ...or anything else to execute, for example, inserting data into a database.

header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($file_url)."\"");
readfile($file_url);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a redirection instead of "complicated" AJAX?

```
 <!-- in your first document -->
 echo '<input type="hidden" name="id_carte" value="'.$row[3].'">';
 echo '<input type="hidden" name="id_user" value="'.$row2[0].'">';
 echo '<a href="download_pdf.php?redirect=' . $row[2] .'">download</a>';
```

and in download_pdf.php

```
<?php
require('./database_connection.php');
...
mysql_close($con);

header("location: " . $_GET['redirect']);
```

Comment: I've tried this too, it's not working. Furthermore I need the file to be executed every time when a pdf is downloaded, meaning every time when the user clicks the anchor

Answer (score 0):

You're lacking basic skill of debugging. If I was you, I should:

1. Use a browser which supporting, ex: Chrome with "Network" inspecting tab ready
2. Try click on the link `<a onclick="insert_download()" ...` and see if the ajax request is performed properly (via Network inspecting tab from your chrome). If not, re-check the generated js, otherwise, something wrong with the `download_pdf.php`, follow next step
3. Inspecting `download_pdf.php`: turn on error reporting on the beginning (put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of your file) try echoing something before and/or after any line you suspect that lead to bugs. Then you can see those ajax response from your Network inspecting tab... By doing so, you're going to narrow down which line/scope of code is causing the problem.

Note that the "echoing" trick can be avoid if you have a solid IDE which is supporting debugger.

Hope it can help